ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for "tours_data"."address"(city_id, street, house_number, entrance_number, floor, flat_number)
Я пытаюсь добавить в unique_together новое поле, но получаю данную ошибку.
class Meta:
        db_table = '"tours_data"."address"'
        verbose_name = _('address')
        verbose_name_plural = _('addresses')
        unique_together = (
            (
                'city',
                'street',
                'house_number', 
                'entrance_number',
                'floor',
                'flat_number',
                'point',
            ),
        )

Нашел информацию, что ошибка возникает из-за того что поля не одинаковые и избежать ее можно если закомментировать AlterUniqueTogether в прошлой миграции, но это звучит как-то костыльно. Есть еще способы это исправить?
